# What does aws volume "insufficient data" means?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

my volume has low io use and has many space left,
but the volume status shows "insufficient data".

this is really confusing, and the aws doc didn't describe about this.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-volume-status.html

Comment: and this status show now since I found is last week

Comment: Are you referring to statistics in Amazon CloudWatch? If so, sometimes CloudWatch does not store (or is not sent) metrics when the value is Zero. Therefore, it is saying that CloudWatch has not been sent enough 'non-zero' values to provide a statistic. Therefore, just think of it as zero. (But please tell us what statistic you are viewing.)

Comment: no, this alert shown at EC2 - Volumes page.
now disappear...